# Designing composable function

Tags: android, function, design-patterns, composition, composable

I am new to android composables. I just had a discussion with my senior  on the way we write composable functions. He suggested that passing objects as funtions parameter would result in recomposition if object value changes (not state objects. plain data objects like json) and it generally a bad practise
If functions acccepts 10-12 parameters is  a bad way to pass data class as funtion params?.
For normal funtions we can go for builder patterns but what about compose?

```
@Composable
fun reusableComp(val params:Params){
   ........
   .........
 }
```

Vs

```
@Composable
fun reusableComp(val param1:String ,val param2:Int?=0..........,val pram12:Int?=0){
   ........
   .........
 }
```

Comment: Looking at how base-functions in `Compose` are written by the Android team, the second approach seems more reasonable, every "base" composable they created accept a lot of parameters, with defaults

Comment: agreed. is there any specific reason why that patterns is used?

Comment: Maybe for the reason your senior suggested: if a single value changes, only the `@composable` that uses that specific value will re-compose. If you use an object, the entire object would be recognised as changed, so the entire `@composable` would be re-composed.

Comment: I think composables does not recompose when object changes then thier would not be any difference between mutable  state and  normal variables , It only changes when the value of the  componests are refering to changes.  I will run sample code to test the same

Comment: here is something more to add https://medium.com/@takahirom/cautions-for-using-classes-of-other-modules-as-arguments-of-composable-functions-in-jetpack-compose-b26f1e1dfc9d

Comment: It depends on the "level" of composable. The first approach is best for top-level composable, containing many nested composable, and needs to provide state and callbacks. The second is best for bottom-level or "base" composable.

Comment: @Geka I disagree. You really want to avoid an entire top-level function to re-compose because something in a `data class` has changed, which might need only a small `Text {}` to change